# Perl6 string coercion operator ~ doesn't like leading zeros

Tags: coercion, raku

I'm toying with Rakudo Star 2015.09.

If I try to stringify an integer with a leading zero, the compiler issues a warning:

```
> say (~01234).WHAT
Potential difficulties:
    Leading 0 does not indicate octal in Perl 6.
    Please use 0o123 if you mean that.
    at <unknown file>:1
    ------> say (~0123<HERE>).WHAT
(Str)
```

I thought maybe I could help the compiler by assigning the integer value to a variable, but obtained the same result:

```
> my $x = 01234; say (~$x).WHAT
Potential difficulties:
    Leading 0 does not indicate octal in Perl 6.
    Please use 0o1234 if you mean that.
    at <unknown file>:1
    ------> my $x = 01234<HERE>; say (~$x).WHAT
(Str)
```

I know this is a silly example, but is this by design? If so, why?

And how can I suppress this kind of warning message?

Comment: I'd say the answer is "don't use ambiguous literals".

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams : `> my $x = sprintf "%05d", 1234; say (~$x).WHAT` doesn't emit the warning

Comment: That's because both `"%05d"` and `1234` are unambiguous.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams : I think you're onto something... `my $x = sprintf "%05d", 01234;...` results in the warning

Comment: It's also possible to preserve the string representation of a number by using an allomorphic value like `IntStr`, eg via `val("01234")` or `< 01234 >`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Is there a reason you have data with leading zeroes? I tend to run into this problem when I have a column of postal codes.

When they were first thinking about Perl 6, one of the goals was to clean up some consistency issues. We had `0x` and `0b` (I think by that time), but Perl 5 still had to look for the leading `0` to guess it would be octal. See [Radix Markers in Synopsis 2](http://design.perl6.org/S02.html#Radix_markers).

But, Perl 6 also has to care about what Perl 5 programmers are going to try to do and what they expect. Most people are going to expect a leading `0` to mean octal. But, it doesn't mean octal. It's that you typed the literal, not how you are using it. Perl 6 has lots of warnings about things that Perl 5 people would try to use, like `foreach`:

```
$ perl6 -e 'foreach @*ARGS -> $arg { say $arg }' 1 2 3
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling -e
Unsupported use of 'foreach'; in Perl 6 please use 'for' at -e:1
------> foreach⏏ @*ARGS -> $arg { say $arg }
```

To suppress that sort of warning, don't do what it's warning you about. The language doesn't want you to do that. If you need a string, start with a string `'01234'`. Or, if you want it to be octal, start with `0o`. But, realize that stringifying a number will get you back the decimal representation:

```
$ perl6 -e 'say ~0o1234'
668
```

Comment: What about the final question. Can the warning be suppressed?

Comment: I had to do `perl -E 'say 01234'` to figure out that this is Perl 5 legacy... the things you learn every day :)

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that a leading '0' implying octal (or leading '0x' implying hex) only applies to *literal values in your program source code*. Leading zeroes on data you read in from a file will not have any effect on how the value is interpreted - numbers will always be treated as decimal.

Comment: @ikegami: `quietly { … } ` suppresses warnings.